# git tells me my local master is 32 commits ahead of origin/master but I don't know what they are. How can I find them?

Tags: git

Which command should I use to identify the 32 commits which git indicates have been made locally but not pushed/merged?

Comment: `git show-branch master origin/master`

Comment: Install gitk and then run `gitk -a` or do `git diff origin/master`. If you have configured git to use a graphical diff tool it's better to do `git difftool origin/master`. For Windows I really like the program "winmerge" (google it). For OSX and Linux I like "meld". After installing your graphical diff program run `git config --global diff.tool winmerge` or `meld` etc. Then you can do `git difftool origin/master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say

```
git log master ^origin/master
```

Or, if you're already on `master`, you can just say

```
git log origin/master..
```

Either way, that lists the commits reachable from `master` but not from `origin/master`, which is exactly what you are asking to know. In fact, Git's own idea of "ahead" comes from performing exactly that sort of operation.